Improperly installed drip edge hinders water drainage?
My newly received apartment has a recessed balcony. From the moment I received the keys, I noticed defects along the edge of the roof above the balcony. The concrete was slightly damaged, revealing the aggregates that make up the concrete. During heavy rains, water tended to flow back inside along the roof (although it remained moderate). Recently, some rope access technicians (hired by the building contractor) came to install a drip edge to fix this issue (and to cover the defects rather than repair them). It seems to me that they did not install the drip edge correctly. The drip edge creates a horizontal strip above the wall's descent, where water can accumulate and take the time to seep horizontally along the slab. I have already noticed a new water mark during a heavy rain. The photo below shows the current installation, with an explanatory diagram that I hope is clear enough.
Can someone tell me if this installation is indeed incorrect? If so, how should the situation be fixed?
EDIT: to answer a question of @JACK, I'm adding a picture of the roof before the installation of the drip edge. You will see another sort of drip edge on this picture, which had been glued to the roof; its removal caused further damage to the concrete slab. Most apartments had no problem with their drip edge to begin with; one other apartment is in the same situation as mine but I haven't heard from them yet.




Are you renting?

How big is that concrete defect? Small defects are not usually fixed because patching material usually won't adhere to small areas.

Did they install drip edges on all the slabs or just yours?

The situation could be fixed with the application of a quality roof sealer applied between the slab and the drip edge from the top. I doubt you'll get rope technicians back to do that since it's an outside patio exposed to rain.

So you think I should just let go and not try to get it fixed? It's quite tricky for me to get there but I may try to do something myself then. I don't think that a sealer that one applies with a caulking gun would work though, the defects seem too large to me, in the range of a couple of inches. Maybe I should use some concrete repair product, like SikaQuick-1000 or DAP Ready-to-Use Concrete Patch?

Any concrete repair won't be waterproof between it and the drip edge so water would still seep in. it would be dangerous for you to try to get up there and I doubt the management would send pros to fix it because it's an outside balcony and water dripping would be expected.  You could caulk the inside seam under the slab which would prevent water from dripping down but that's still close to the edge and would require being up on a ladder.
